# Qt3Support for Qt4 on Ubuntu: linker error

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt3

I'm trying to build a Qt3 application from here (it also needs all 4 [gsl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490465/install-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-terminal) packages):

http://robotics.usc.edu/~boyoon/particle.html

Using QtCreator with Qt 4.8.6 and package libqt4-qt3support on Ubuntu 15.10.

I have added all code files to an empty Qt4 project, replaced all Qt includes in the headers with

`#include </usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Qt3Support>`

and changed lines like

```
painter.setPen(white);
```

to

```
painter.setPen(Qt::white);
```

Also I have added the line `QT += qt3support` to project's .pro file.

Now I get a linker error for libQtGui.so.4

```
g++  -o mousetracker1 particle.o mouse_tracker.o kd_tree.o   
        -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQt3Support -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: mouse_tracker.o: undefined reference to symbol 
        '_ZN7QWidget17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4: error adding symbols:
        DSO missing from command line
```

Is there any way for me to build and run this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on virtual machine with qt3 and compiled this application using `./configure` with `CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/qt3" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include/qt3"` and `make`.